# Streamlit - Accessing of dataframe from home page to other page using st.session_state

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

For a multi page application in streamlit. I want to access the object that return from "HomePage" in another page "DataPlotPage". Home page is created for setting the data and another page is to consume data from the HomePage to plot the graph.

**Problem:** When user click on "DataPlotPage" before setting up the data in Homepage, Error appears***"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"*** as the object from the HomePage didn't return valid dataset. How to handle this?

Expected: Expect to provide error message as  st.write("Data is missing, kind load the data in first page")

Here is the example of code.

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

**#HomePage [1st Page]**

mydataset =  st.radio ("**Data method**", [":blue[Upload dataset]", ":blue[Get dataset from jira]" ], index=None)
 
 def getrecord():
   if mydataset== ":blue[Get dataset from jira]":
      df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Key": [23, 45, 67, 89], "Name": ["AB", "BC", "CD", "EF"] }
      return df1
   else:
      df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Key": [50, 60, 70, 80], "Name": ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"] }
  

df = getrecord()
st.session_state["df"] = df # initiated session state to access the data in other page

**#DataPlotPage [2nd Page]**

def dataplot():
    df = st.session_state["df"]
    st.write(df)


 dataplot()
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe send `mydataset` to second page and create `DataFrame` directly in `dataplot`

Comment: This issue is solved by using Try and Exception

Comment: you could describe it as answer below (and show full code). And you can mark your answer as accepted, and later you can upvote it.